# How to handle app links for a webview app

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm trying to handle app links in a webview app.
this means if user click on a link something like `example.com/example.html` the app should show the open with dialogbox.
I've implemented this:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="www.example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And my MainActivity.java contains this code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                ...
                ...

                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.example.com")) {
                    return false;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            }

        });
```

But the problem is that when user open the link using the app, it shows the home screen rather than the clicked link/page.

How can I implement this?

Thanks.